# How can I move between different fullpagejs pages sections without animation?

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

I have a website with 5 pages, each page is a different full page page.
In home page I move between sections without animation with

```
$('.silentMoveTo05').on( "click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    fullpage_api.silentMoveTo(5);
});
```

but if I call the home page from a different page

```
<a href="http://example.com/home/#5">link to slide 5</a>
```

the scroll is with animation

Answer (score 0):

You can use the option `scrollingSpeed:0`, but of course, that will lead to issues when using the mouse wheel or trackpad.

I would encourage to just use a class like `no-animation` and then use JS to call the `silentMoveTo` method:

```
 <a href="http://example.com/home/#5" class="no-animation">Link here</a>
```

And the JS:

```
$('.no-animation').on( "click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var anchor = $(this).attr('href').replace('#', '');
    fullpage_api.silentMoveTo(anchor);
});
```

Reproduction online:
https://jsfiddle.net/alvarotrigo/yagzbr3f/3/

Comment: I just found the solution is to use animateAnchor: false

Comment: That won't work... I'm the author of the fullpage.js component, believe me :)

The only way that can work is if you load the site using fullpage.js from another site. But if you have an internal link in your same site using fullpage.js, that won't do the trick.

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question wasn't clear I did fix for internal link with silentMoveTo(5); the problem was that I still had animation from external pages, since I use fullpage only in home page, and animateAnchor: false seems to fix that too